# How to profile stack size for c programs

Tags: c, stack, profiling

I am trying to optimize a program.
The program do not make use of heap.
I would like to profile the size of the stack to see:

- How big is the stack?
- Where the stack reach its peak?
- What is the trend of the stack size?
- Where i was in the code when i reached the peak of the stack, or, in general, at any point of the stack size trend?

I already tried valgrind with massif in such way:

```bash
valgrind --tool=massif --stacks=yes ./program
```

For example with a simple hello world

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{

    int input;

    scanf("%d", &input);

    if (input == 1)
    {
        printf("Hello world\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Goodbye world\n");
    }
}
```

Compile it

```bash
gcc -o main main.c
```

Run it with valgrind

```bash
buba98@buba-laptop:~/projects$ valgrind --tool=massif --stacks=yes ./main
==18236== Massif, a heap profiler
==18236== Copyright (C) 2003-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Nicholas Nethercote
==18236== Using Valgrind-3.21.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==18236== Command: ./main
==18236== 
1
Hello world
==18236==
```

Comment: In a debugger breakpoint at start and end of program. At start, fill all unused stack with 0. At end examine stack frames past end of current stack to see highest point and what was the caller.

Comment: Thanks I will try. Isn't there a command line tool to Automate it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

// Get stack pointer.
static inline unsigned char *sp() {
    register unsigned char *r;
#if defined(__arm__) || defined(__arm64__) || defined(__aarch64__)
    asm volatile ("mov %0, sp" : "=r" (r));
#elif defined(__x86_64__) || defined(__amd64__)
    asm volatile ("movq %%rsp, %0" : "=r" (r));
#else
#   error unknown architecture
#endif
    return r;
}

unsigned char *top;

void recur(int n) {
    if (n == 0)
        return;
    recur(n - 1);
    printf("n = %d, stack = %zd\n", n, top - sp());
}

int main(void) {
    top = sp();
    recur(10);
    return 0;
}
```

where `sp()` is called in the deepest part of every function, or those functions that you know will push the stack the farthest, with the result of `sp()` tracked how you like. Each `sp()` call should turn into just a single machine instruction in the compiled code with optimization.

In C++ you could rig a `shared_ptr` at the start of a function to run a tracking function when the current function exits, regardless of how it exits.

With optimization, this prints:

```
n = 1, stack = 480
n = 2, stack = 432
n = 3, stack = 384
n = 4, stack = 336
n = 5, stack = 288
n = 6, stack = 240
n = 7, stack = 192
n = 8, stack = 144
n = 9, stack = 96
n = 10, stack = 48
```

You could attempt this with a pointer to a local variable instead of the assembler instruction, but optimizing compilers can be quite aggressive in removing the existence of unused variables.

Note: I put the `printf()` after the `recur()` call to avoid tail optimization, which would use no stack at all!

As for how big the stack is to begin with, in general C programs don't know and don't care. It is defined when linking, so you can look to your compiler documentation for what the default is. For my compiler, it's 8MB. You can tell your linker to make it bigger.

C programs are permitted to merrily and obliviously write past the end of the stack, causing all sorts of mysterious and unfathomable behavior. Hence the name of this site.